# If $\int_1^\infty f(x) \,dx$ converges, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus

If $\int_1^\infty f(x) \,dx$  converges, then $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x) = 0$

true? or false?

Comment: what are your thoughts on the problem? what does the convergence of $\int_1^\infty f(x)\,dx$ imply about $f(x)$? please show some effort in your question and people will be glad to put effort into an answer.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to type your question. Also go through: [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question)

Comment: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Answer (score 2):

No. Counter example:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 1, & \text{$\lfloor x \rfloor \le x \le \lfloor x \rfloor + \frac{1}{2^{\lfloor x \rfloor}}$} \\ 0, & \text{else.} \end{cases}$$

We note that $\int_1^\infty f(x) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^i} = 1$, but $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

False: it is enough to consider

$$ f(x) = \sum_{n\geq 1} n e^{-n^6(x-n)^2}.\tag{1}$$
Over any compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^+$ we have that $f(x)$ is a uniformly convergent series of non-negative continuous functions, hence $f(x)$ is continuous and non-negative. We also have

$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx \leq \sum_{n\geq 1}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} n e^{-n^6(x-n)^2}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^{5/2}}{6}\tag{2} $$
but for any $n\in\mathbb{N}^+$ we have $f(n)\geq n$, contradicting $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$.